# Change IText color in Fabric.JS canvas (using React + typescript)

Tags: html, typescript, canvas, fabricjs

I have `input` with `type=color` outside `Canvas`. I have `canvas` with one ore more `IText` objects (as well as other objects). What I wanted to achieve is "on input change, change color of select text objects".

**This is my input within React**

```
<input type="color" defaultValue={defaultTextColor} ref={myRef} onChange={handleColorChange} />
```

I am able to change "text", but not color...

**This is my Color Change event**

```
const handleColorChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const newColor = e.currentTarget.value;
    canvas.getActiveObjects().forEach((element: any) => {
      if(element.type == 'i-text') {
          element.color = newColor; //this doesn't work
          element.text = "new"; // this works
      }
    });
    
    canvas.renderAll();
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the color of a text is defined in the property ***fill***

Then you need to use the ***set*** and [***renderAll***](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#renderAll) functions.

Here is an example

```
        var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas");
        var myText = new fabric.Text("Hello", {
            top: 100,
            left: 100,
            width: 60,
            height: 70,
            fill: "red",
        });
        setTimeout(() => {
            myText.set("fill", "green");
            canvas.renderAll();
        }, 2000);

        canvas.add(myText);
```

Comment: Changing Why we have to use setTimeout?

Comment: Sorry you don't need to use a setTimeout, it was there just to show the color change if you run the code without an input field